# com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: Cannot read from backfilling global secondary index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

We keep getting this exception in our app which has a scheduled job to read on a gloabl secondary index. Looks like it keeps backfilling periodically even though there were no changes on the table. The volumes on our table are quite low so a bit surprised to see this a few times a day.
This is not a new index, so wondering should it not backfill only on insert/update of records. 
Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 47):

It might be creating that GSI. Wait for sometime based on the amount of data in your DB. And this issue will go away.

Comment: How long does it take for this to be fixed? We created the indexes and accessed it 3-4 hrs after the status was active

Comment: Index will be available in 10 minutes or less

Answer (score 13):

I just waited 30 seconds, the error was gone away automatically. I edited my dynamoDB table from my aws console directly, I think this temporary error originated from this.

Answer (score 7):

This error occurs when you newly create a GSI in dynamodb Table. wait for sometimes once it get created into the table you will not see the error
see in below image it says Creating...
[image]

it will be like
[image]

then hit your function you will not get an error

Answer (score 0):

Try Detecting and Correcting Index Key Violations. I guess it is due to Index key Violation.

Comment: "the key values in a global secondary index do not need to be unique".I have only one key on the index. It is not unique but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: May be then datatype mismatch

Comment: check this --> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.ViolationDetection.html